# I want to open popover on react-google-map

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I want to open a popover when a particular shape is clicked like this
[image]

This my code of what i have tried

```
<Popover
  placement="top"
  content={() => content(poly)}
  trigger="click"
  className="crime-marker"
>
  {" "}
  <Polygon
    ref={(ref) => {
      _polyRef(ref);
    }}
    paths={poly.coord}
    onClick={(value) => console.log(poly)}
    onMouseDown={() => {
      _onMousedown(index);
    }}
  />
</Popover>
```

But Nothing is happening when i am trying this..
Can somebody help me with this
Thankyou in advance